# How to insert text nodes at specific locations with lxml?

Tags: python, html, lxml

If `tostring(root)` is something like:

```xml
<root><child1></child1><child2></child2></root>
```

and one wants to insert plain, (maybe even already escaped) text before `child1`; between the two children; and after `child2` with `lxml`, how one should do that exactly? I'm asking, because it looks like, there is no separate text-node in `lxml`, one can only access the `text` property of an `Element`, and I couldn't find any solutions in the API documentation either...

Anyway, the desired end result would look something like this:

```xml
<root>text1<child1></child1>text2<child2></child2>text3</root>
```

Comment: how about `xml.etree.ElementTree` solution?

Comment: ..and so, why the `-1`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest would you care elaborate on that one?

Comment: I wouldn't, because I have already accepted the answer

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you could still earn an upvote if it is worthy, not to mention if it is different than the currently accepted one, maybe others will find your solution more useful..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To insert text before any children of a node, use the node's `text` attribute.

To insert text after the child of a node, use that child's `tail` attribute.

```
from lxml import etree
s = "<root><child1></child1><child2></child2></root>"
root = etree.XML(s)
root.text = "text1"
child1, child2 = root.getchildren()
child1.tail = "text2"
child2.tail = "text3"
print(etree.tostring(root, method="c14n")) #use this method to prevent self-closing tags in output
```

Result:

```
b'<root>text1<child1></child1>text2<child2></child2>text3</root>'
```

Answer (score 0):

The text attribute seems to do the job. Setting it seems simple enough.

```
test="<root><child1></child1><child2></child2></root>"
from lxml import etree
root = etree.fromstring(test)
etree.tostring(root)
b'<root><child1/><child2/></root>'
print(root.text)
None
root.text = '1'
print(root.text)
1
etree.tostring(root)
b'<root>1<child1/><child2/></root>'
for child in root:
    child.text = 'test'
etree.tostring(root)
b'<root>1<child1>test</child1><child2>test</child2></root>'
```

Now if you need text after the element ended, then you need the tail attribute of the element.

```
for child in root:
    child.text = None
    child.tail = 'tail'
```

Comment: But he wants the second and third strings to be _outside_ the child1 and child2 tags.

Comment: Then he needs to use a combination of text and tail. The answer below gets it right I think